# AngularFire2 - Firebase how to filter a query?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

```
    subscribeQueryPostsByUsernameAndCategory(username: string, category: string) {
    return  this.af.database.list('posts', {
        query: {
            orderByChild: 'username',
            equalTo: username,
        }
    });
```

Now each post object has a username and a category property. I want to be able to get all the posts of a specific username and category.

How can I either had a filter for the category or just assign the return to a variable and do some kind of loop to check the property before returning?

Thanks

Comment: Use rxjs filters.

Comment: The Firebase Database can only order by/filter on a single property. You may be able to combine the two values into a single property to accomplish your use-case. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase. I also recommend checking out this video, which covers the same approach: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sKFLI5FOOHs&index=4&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s